# Unable to move Boxplot chart successfully

Tags: excel, vba

I have been looking around the web and have since gathered some codes that will create a box plot and move it to another worksheet. However, the following code is able to create the box plot but unable to move it to a new sheet and when it tried, this error pops up

> Run-time error '1004' Method 'Location' of object '_Chart' failed

on this line

```
Set c = c.Location(where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="newChartSheetName")
```

and when i tried to run it again, my excel file will just close itself without saving. I have tried to create a boxplot at the worksheet i wanted it to be but the data is from another worksheet which makes the chart empty which is why i changed to this method. The following is my current attempt to this problem. Appreciate any help given.

```
Sub test_boxplot()
    Dim chart_title As String
    Dim RngToCover As Range
    Dim ChtOb As ChartObject, c As Chart

    With Sheets("Data")
        .Select
        .Range("E6:E425").Select ' I understand this is not an efficient way to go about it.

        chart_title = .Range("E2")

        .Shapes.AddChart2(408, xlBoxwhisker).Select
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = chart_title
    End With

    With Sheets("Graphs")
        Set RngToCover = .Range("L6:O23")      
    End With

    Set ChtOb = ActiveChart.Parent
    Set c = ChtOb.Chart

    Set c = c.Location(where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="newChartSheetName") 'Error here    
    c.Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)         

    With ChtOb
        .Height = RngToCover.Height ' resize
        .Width = RngToCover.Width   ' resize
        .Top = RngToCover.Top       ' reposition
        .Left = RngToCover.Left     ' reposition
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: **1.** If I'm not wrong then `.Location where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet` gives an error for BoxPlot but successfully moves the chart. You can use `On Error Resume Next | On Error Go To 0` to tackle this error. **2.** There is also one more issue. The name successfuly will change to `"newChartSheetName"` but will not reflect in the VBE Project Properties. It'll show as `ChartXXX`, The name will only display in the VBE once the file is saved. Couldn't find any MS KB to support my above statement. You can try & test it your self.

Comment: **3.** In case you try & create a `columnclustered` chart & then move it as a chart sheet, it'll let you but then it'll not let you use `.ChartType` to change it to `xlBoxwhisker` **4.** Tested in Excel 2016

Comment: Yes, it did move the chart but i was confused as to why it did move but still throws an error. I was actually thinking of using ```On Error Resume Next``` but i have came across many posts that say it is not advised to do so which is why i avoided it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using OERN if you know how to use it. :) In you case you will add OERN before `.Location(where:=` and add `On Error GoTo 0` right after.

Comment: Also avoid using `.Select/Activechart etc`, Work with objects. It will make your life easier. Also check if the chart was created. Let me know if you want a sample code on how to tackel all this :)

Comment: I was actually finding different ways to not use ```.Activate``` or ```.Select``` for charts but the codes i found to create the chart is unable to work for the chart type ```xlBoxwhisker```. It would be amazing if you could provide a sample code @SiddharthRout and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If I'm not wrong then `.Location where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet` gives an error for BoxPlot but successfully moves the chart. You can use `On Error Resume Next | On Error Go To 0` to tackle this error.
2. There is also one more issue. The name successfuly will change to **newChartSheetName** but will not reflect in the VBE Project Properties. It'll show as **ChartXXX** as shown in the image below. The name will only display in the VBE once the file is saved, closed and re-opened. The name does get updated in the **Properties** window though. Couldn't find any MS KB to support my above statement. You can try & test it your self.

   [image]
3. In case you try & create a columnclustered chart & then move it as a chart sheet, it'll let you but then it'll not let you use `.ChartType` to change it to `xlBoxwhisker`. It will give you `The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type` error. This is usually when Excel is unable to create/convert to complex chart types.
4. There was an alternative but that is a definite bug. `Charts.Add` has a 4th parameter which is `Type:=` where you could have specified `xlBoxwhisker` but fails with Runtime Error 1004. This is a bug since Excel 2007. You cannot use this for any other type as well.
5. Also avoid using `.Select/Activechart`. Use objects and work with them. It will make your life easier.

Here is an example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsChrt As Chart
    Dim objChart As ChartObject
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim shp As Shape

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    '~~> Delete existing chart if any
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    '~~> Create new chart and move
    With ws
         Set shp = .Shapes.AddChart2(408, xlBoxwhisker, 200, 100, 350, 200, True) '
         Set objChart = .ChartObjects(shp.Name)
         Set chrt = objChart.Chart

         With chrt
            '~~> Set your source data here
            .SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("E6:E11")

            On Error Resume Next
            .Location where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="test"
            Set wsChrt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test")
            On Error GoTo 0
         End With

        If Not wsChrt Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Chart Moved"
            With wsChrt
                '
                '~~> Do what you want with the chart
                '
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "Error in creating a chart"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, i have tried no.4 it indeed throws a runtime error. I have noticed no.2 as well when i was playing around with it the other time but this explains why it happens. Thank you once again for taking your time to teach me and showing me what is the right way to it.  Really appreciate it!